# which shortcut to use in intellij with ideavim instead of escape which I normally used to close windows (or get back.. escape..)

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I really like `ideavim` however I'm used to click <kbd>Escape</kbd> in order to... `escape` the current position into previous ones, sometimes its just closing the `diff` windows, and someone its just closing the current popup.  However after installing `ideavim` it appears <kbd>Escape</kbd> is now used for `exit edit mode`, so what is my current replacement for my <kbd>Escape</kbd> button which will do the same operation <kbd>Escape</kbd> was doing without `ideavim`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<C-c>` or `<C-[>`. See [VIM-740](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-740) for more info.